# Bridge to objc, how can it knows arguments types?

Tags: objective-c, compilation, scripting-bridge

I am writing a bridge from a language I am developing and ObjC.
There are several nice introspection C functions in the objective C runtime and I am able to retrieve arguments types for methods using method_getTypeEncoding.

The main problem is with object arguments which are returned as id (encoded as @) but what I would need is the real objc class name like NSString or NSNumber.

Is there a way to solve this issue without parsing the .h files?

Comment: You mean something like `NSStringFromClass(Class aClass)`? Though if you call this for built-in objc classes, I think you get their runtime equivalents (so, `__NSCFString` instead of `NSString`). If so, then you're going to want to browse the objc runtime environment [https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/]

Answer (score 0):

Knowing something is an id allows you to know the size of the parameter, which is important when writing a scripting interface.  Add another layer where you can dynamically verify assumptions using things like

```
[objectPassedIn isKindOfClass: [expectedType class]];
```

You want to be careful hardcoding things like, "Oh this is a string so look for __NSCFString" - because there's no way to know you'll get an instance of __NSCFString or another type.  NSString is a class cluster - You could get any custom implementation back when using one.

The actual type of objects is not important to the Objective-C Runtime so you need to add your own layer.  You might be able to get some useful info using Clang/llvm as a tool.